Put specific name on plt.title using DataFrame
I want to plot a graph with the column name in the title.
For example:
import pandas as pd
begin_date = '2019-01-01'
    
df = pd.DataFrame ({"date": pd.date_range(begin_date, periods=5),
  "John": [42, 40, 47, 49, 51],
  "Ana": [50, 43, 41, 46,47],
  "Goku": [55, 58, 62, 64, 69],                  
})


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df["John"])

I'll plot the graph using this last line with the John values.
I want to create something like this:
plt.title("Name of graph: John")

But how do I select the column name and put it in plt.title?
I have to do this in a dataframe which has more than 20 names, and I want to automate this.
Is that possible?

You can create a for loop -
for column in df.columns[1:]:
    plt.figure():
    plt.plot(df["date"], df[column]) 
    plt.show()


This i'll help me. Thanks!
